How to mount a configMap into a persistentVolumeClaim?
So, I'm trying to teach myself kubernetes by example, and I've found a scenario I can't seem to find a good solution to. The general scenario is a container requires a config to have a path like /config/system.xml, but there are also auto-created embedded databases and such also created in /config. So, my initial thought was to have a persistentVolumeClaim for /config, and simply mount the configMap into the PVC. The problem I'm having is, system.xml IS mounted, and has the correct content, but also has owner/group = root, and the container logs indicate the /config/system.xml is a "read-only" filesystem.
I've tried a few things to get this working:

securityContext to try to make the system.xml in the appropriate non-root use/group
using the subPath directive for system.xml
initContainers to wget the config files from github (this kinda works, but seems like a hack)

Does anyone have any suggestions for handling this scenario?

deployment.yml (utilizing subPath shown):
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jellyfin
  labels:
    app: jellyfin
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jellyfin
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jellyfin
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: jellyfin
          image: lscr.io/linuxserver/jellyfin:10.9.9ubu2204-ls25
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8096
          volumeMounts:
          # NFS mounts ommitted
          - name: jf-config
            mountPath:  /config
          - name: jf-config-system
            mountPath:  /config/system.xml
            subPath:  system.xml
      volumes:
      # NFS mounts ommitted
      - name: jf-config
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName:  jf-config-data
      - name: jf-config-system
        configMap:
          name: jf-baseconfig-configmap

pcv.yml:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: jf-config-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: longhorn
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi

kustomization.yml:
---
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: dev

configMapGenerator:
- name: jf-baseconfig-configmap
  files:
  - system.xml

generatorOptions:
  labels:
    app: jellyfin

resources:
- ../../base

namePrefix: dev-

patches:
- path: svc_IP.yml    # not shown; works fine

there are some other files/folders omitted for the sake of space.

background:
My kubernetes (k3s) cluster is running on VMs within Proxmox, and I'm making use of KubeVIP, MetalLB, and Longhorn (basically following this and this)

Can you fix your application's Dockerfile and/or configuration so that data and configuration aren't stored in the same place?  In Unix in general you can't usually mount individual files, only whole directories, and while Kubernetes and Docker have some cleverness to pretend otherwise I could see these conflicting if you're using the same directory for both file and directory mounts.

Sadly not, as it isn't my image. But I'll look into writing/tweaking my own. Would I be correct in thinking that this might just not be possible without changing something outside kubernetes?
